# Integrate Cypress code coverage with Sonar

Tags: json, sonarqube, cypress, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan

So I know a html report is generated by default with cypress code-coverage , but I was hoping to use Sonar to represent /store my coverage.
Currently its generated ,json report which I believe sonar does not use for .js files.

Any help is appreciated.

Tried nyc to generate report in different formats but no luck

-Dsonar.testExecutionReportPaths=coverage-final.json

-Dsonar.apex.coverage.reportPath=coverage-final.json

Comment: If you're using Cypress for code coverage and want to integrate it with Sonar for JavaScript files, you'll need to convert the coverage report generated by Cypress from JSON format to a format that Sonar can understand, such as LCOV. https://www.npmjs.com/package/codecov-json-to-lcov

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem --

```
nyc report --reporter=lcov --report-dir=.nyc_coverage
```

OR in package.json add --

> ```
> "nyc": {
>         "report-dir": "coverage-cy",
>         "reporter": [
>             "json",
>             "html",
>             "lcov"
>         ],
>        }
> ```

This by default will generate lcov with html and json